# Adding binary numbers in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, binary, decimal

I have a function which takes two binary numbers as an array of integers, adds the numbers, then returns the sum as a new array of integers.

```
public static int[] addBin(int a[], int b[]){
      int[] sum = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
      int carryover = 0;
      int randombanana = 0;
      int x = 7;
      for(x = 7; x > 0; x--){
        randombanana = a[x] + a[x] + carryover;
        if(randombanana == 1){
          sum[x] = 1;
          carryover = 0;
        }
        else if(randombanana == 2){
          sum[x] = 0;
          carryover = 1;
        }
        else if(randombanana == 3){
          sum[x] = 1;
          carryover = 1;
        }
        else if(randombanana == 0){
          sum[x] = 0;
          carryover = 0;
        }
        else{
          System.out.println("Either I [censored] up, or you [censored] up.  I'm a genius so I'm going to assume you [censored] up");
        }
      }
          if(carryover == 1){
            sum[x] = 1;
      }
      return sum;
    }
```

The code works fine on single digit numbers, including numbers that require carrying a digit, but on double or triple digit numbers it works when a number is added to itself, but not when different multiple digit numbers are added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be

```
randombanana = a[x] + b[x] + carryover;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop isn't handling the 0th bit

```
for(x = 7; x >= 0; x--){
```

Comment: The final bit is handled in a separate if statement outside of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two numbers are of the same length the numbers could be added as follows:

```
public static int[] addNumbers(int[] firstNum, int[] secondNum) {
        int[] result = new int[firstNum.length + 1];
        int digitSum, carry = 0, i;
        for (i = firstNum.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            digitSum = firstNum[i] + secondNum[i] + carry;
            result[i + 1] = digitSum % 2;
            carry = digitSum / 2;
        }
        result[0] = carry;
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short and crisp solution.

```
 public static int [] addBinaryNumbers(int a[],int b[])
    {
        int n =Integer.max(a.length, b.length);
        int c[]=new int[n+1];
        int carry =0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            c[n-i]=(a[i]+b[i]+carry)%2;
            carry= (a[i]+b[i]+carry) /2;
        }
        c[n]=carry;
        return c;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).